# How to use error page at web config in c# , so

Tags: c#

I want to use error page.. suppose i get error at my work page, it should dispaly an error page.. if i debug error and try again to come back, i get same error page...

Can anyone help out exact way to write error page in web config..

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error.htm">
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="error500.aspx"/>
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="filenotfound.aspx"/>
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="authorizationfailed.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx" mode="On"></customErrors>
```

And for custom errors based on error code:

```
  <customErrors defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx" mode="On">   
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="servererror.aspx" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="filenotfound.aspx" />
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="AccessDenied.aspx" /> 
    </customErrors>
```